# PHP Cookie Error after changing session

Tags: php

I have code an User Dasboard yesterday and now if i Login as an User theres comes this Error Message in Browser:

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

Its the same Error in all Browsers, i have delete all cookies, but  i think its an Problem from my Script because i have add some new code to the Script.

Some User logins Works perfect the other cant load the Dashboard and the error comes.

Code i have changed in header file, in this line `$userdetails = mysql_fetch_array`:

```
<?php
require_once('../function.php');
require_once("anotifier.php");

connectdb();
session_start();

if (!is_user()) {
redirect("$baseurl/signin");
}



$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$sid = $_SESSION['sid'];

$userdetails = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT id, firstname, mallu, block, sid, mv, btc, iban, lastname, bic, bicde, ibande FROM users WHERE email='".$user."'"));
$uid = $userdetails[0];
$mallu = $userdetails[2];
$ufnm = $userdetails[1];
$btc= $userdetails[6];
$iban= $userdetails[7];
$lastname= $userdetails[8];
$bic= $userdetails[9];
$bicde= $userdetails[10];
$ibande= $userdetails[11];

if($sid!=$userdetails[4]){
redirect("$baseurl/signout");
}


if($userdetails[3]==1){
redirect("$baseurl/signout");
}


if($userdetails[5]==0){
redirect("$baseurl/verify");
}
$gen = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT sitetitle FROM general_setting WHERE id='1'"));

?>
```

Dont know whats are the Problem because some Users can Login the other one not.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Try putting `return;` or `exit;` after your `redirect()` statements. I think that multiple redirect-header get send and the browser cant handle that.